# How do you create an account dashboard for each user registration using WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am creating a website for online learning and I am not a coder.

My questions are:

1. Can we have our own user-base in WordPress? If yes, help me in the identification of that.
2. If Yes to the above question, do we need to maintain our own DB or something of that sort?
3. If Yes again, then how can I redirect to dashboard page/ upgrade page/ billing page based on the login credentials and other specific preferences?

Choice of the platform is WordPress + Elementor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [user-registarion](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-registration/) plugin to get the job done.

where you can create

1. User registration form and login form.
2. No need to maintain your own DB.
3. You can redirect to dashboard page/ upgrade page/ billing page
   based on the login credentials and other specific preferences.
   [check out their documentation](https://docs.wpeverest.com/user-registration/)